# Sorting maps value within 2 list by value flutter

Tags: dart

can i sort about value in map within list??
expect result: [1,2,3,4,6,7]

```
List a = [
        [
          {'g': 1},
          {'g': 5},
          {'g': 3}
        ],
        [
          {'g': 7},
          {'g': 2}
        ],
        [
          {'g': 4}
        ]
      ];
```

Comment: In general, If you have a structure like this, you should consider making some classes instead. Also, your question does not make it clear what you want? Based on the requested result it looks like you want to extract the numbers and then sort them into a new list?

Answer (score 1):

1. Loop through the map of the data `a` and add the value to a list.
2. Sort the list

```html
List a = [
                        [
                          {'g': 1},
                          {'g': 5},
                          {'g': 3}
                        ],
                        [
                          {'g': 7},
                          {'g': 2}
                        ],
                        [
                          {'g': 4}
                        ]
                      ];
                      List<int> values = [];
                      for (var o in a) {
                        for (var i in o) {
                          values.add(i['g']);
                        }
                      }
                      values.sort((a, b) => a - b);
                      print(values);
```

Output:

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Don't use this pattern of `map` and then calling `toList()` just to get it to iterate over all elements. If you want to do some operation for each element in the list, use the `forEach()` method on `a`. Or just write a normal for loop which iterates over the elements.

Comment: agreed. Updated the answer

Comment: Also try: `var values = [for (var list in a) for (var map in list) map["g"] as int]..sort()`.